# How to import Eviews data into pandas

Tags: pandas, statistics, time-series, eviews

I am unfortunately only given datasets for my time series course as an Eviews wf1 file. How can I import this into pandas? I cannot find an answer in pandas online documentation.

Comment: Can you open it in Eviews, export to csv and then load to pandas?

Comment: unfortunately we have to access eviews through a remote desktop connection which my computer cannot do currently :( i am currently trying to open it in gretl and export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around solution I have just found is to:
(1) Download gretl, an open-source econometrics software, see http://gretl.sourceforge.net

(2) open the Eviews file into Gretl

(3) export from Gretl as csv.